# How to configure a Zepplin notebook to use only X cores in my local Spark Cluster?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Config - Ubuntu; Apache Zepplin (7.3.0); Spark 2.2.0; Hadoop 2.6;

A cluster of 6 machines with 14gb ram & 4 cores each. Need to split these for two notebooks. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of 7.3.0, check-in Zepplin Interpreter settings.

A dropdown option is available select the SparkContext as `Global` or `per Note`.